# knitr chunk options to control line spacing, font size in output

Tags: latex, font-size, knitr

I'd like to have more control over the font size and line spacing used for 
code chunks and R output via LaTeX.  Using the default render_latex(), I see I can
set both globally using (in my premable)

```
\renewenvironment{knitrout}{\small\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.85}}{} 
...
\begin{document}
```

But, say there are chunks I'd like to print in \footnotesize, or customize in some other
way.  I know I can do this with a LaTeX group, but not with the knitrout environment:

```
{\small
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.85}
<<arth-csv, eval=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
ID,Treatment,Sex,Age,Improved
57,Treated,Male,27,Some
46,Treated,Male,29,None
...
71,Placebo,Female,68,Some
1,Placebo,Female,74,Marked
@
}
```

Would it be easier to do this using render_listings() and the listings package?

Can I use custom chunk options and chunk hooks to achieve better control?

Answer (score 4):

To partially answer my own question, I discovered the knitr `size=` chunk option, which works, AFAIK, only with
`render_latex()` and the highlight package.  Thus, for a wide output to be set in footnote size, I can use

```
<<tv3, size="footnotesize">>=
TV <- TV[,,1:3,]     # keep only ABC, CBS, NBC
TV <- TV[,,,3]       # keep only Persist -- now a 3 way table
structable(TV)
@
```

Also, the example I used above with `results='asis'` should have been done just with a `verbatim` LaTeX environment,
not as as code chunk.  Even though I had used `eval=FALSE`, knitr tries to parse the text and generates a warning.

```
{\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.85}
\begin{verbatim}
ID,Treatment,Sex,Age,Improved
57,Treated,Male,27,Some
46,Treated,Male,29,None
...
71,Placebo,Female,68,Some
1,Placebo,Female,74,Marked
\end{verbatim}
}
```

Comment: set `tidy=FALSE, highlight=FALSE` and knitr will no longer parses the code